# Displaying 2 groups of Firebase data in different cell nibs

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database structured like this:

[image: Screen Shot]

```
var posts = [Post]()
var songs = [Song]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
   tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")

    let songNib = UINib(nibName: "SongTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(songNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "songCell")
```

I have 2 different nibs and am able to extract data, but I'm unsure how to structure the indexPath.row test so that my table view rows can switch which cell style it shows based on which group of data the array belongs to. I currently have a test with a static if function, but obviously only displays "song" data after "post" data

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count + songs.count
  }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < posts.count {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    } else {

        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "songCell", for: indexPath) as! SongTableViewCell
        cell2.set(song: songs[indexPath.row-posts.count])

        return cell2
     }

   }
```

---------EDIT----------

```
class Post:Item {

var imageURL: String!

 convenience init(id: String, author: UserProfile, text: String, timestamp: Double, imageURL: String) {

    self.init(id: id, author: author, text: text, timestamp: timestamp, imageURL: imageURL)

    self.imageURL = imageURL
  }   
 }
```

**OR**

```
class Post:Item {

var imageURL: String!

init(id: String, author: UserProfile, text: String, timestamp: Double, imageURL: String) {
    super.init(id: id, author: author, text: text, timestamp: timestamp)
    self.imageURL = imageURL
    }
 }
```

Comment: Share the UI design how you want to display the data.

Comment: "songs" are displayed like [this](https://imgur.com/vB5vIo0) and "posts" are displayed like [this](https://imgur.com/ayN71yf)

Comment: Ok but how do you know first you have to show Songs or posts?

Comment: I guess that's my question, how I should restructure the Firebase db to accommodate two cell types. I think instead of having two root folders - songs and posts - I would need to put all children under one root instead and have each uploaded post tagged with the post type

Comment: But if I do this how would I structure the cellForRowAt indexPath function to assign cell type based on the tag instead of indexPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to have one timeline with two types of items: `Post` and `Song`.
So one way to do this would be to have one superclass and two subclasses `Post` and `Song`

```
class Item
    author
    timestamp
    ... other common properties

class Post: Item
    text
    ...

class Song: Item
    songName
    ...
```

Then you can have just array of `Item` objects

```
var items = [Item]()
```

and then instead of appending posts and songs to posts and songs array append it just to `items` array.

Also you can sort your items array by `timestamp` property

```
items.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp > $1.timestamp })
```

Finally in `numberOfRowsInSection` data source method return just number of items

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}
```

and in `cellForRowAt` data source method set cell depends if item is `Song` or `Post`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    if let song = item as? Song {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "songCell", for: indexPath) as! SongTableViewCell
        cell.set(song: song)
        return cell

    } else if let post = item as? Post {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.set(post: post)
        return cell

    } else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. For clarification, the data for 'post' type and 'song' type are not going to be as similar as they are right now which is why I made each its own class instead of using subclasses. How would I initialize in that way?

Comment: Then you should have superclass which has common properties like `author` etc. and two subclasses. And then in `cellForRowAt` do the same `if let song = superclass as? Song`...

Comment: I see now. Why not `Post: Item` and `Song:Item` though?

Comment: Hey, I'm getting everything to run but I think I'm overlooking something in the initialization of my Post subclass

`class Item { 
...
init(id:String, author:UserProfile, text:String, timestamp: Double) { ..`

Comment: Added an edit to OP, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: @diligentcrush use just init (second option in your question) and for `imageUrl` property use instead of `String!` just `String`

Comment: @diligentcrush add to your question code of Item superclass

Comment: hey check your DMs

Comment: @diligentcrush DM?

Comment: twitter messages

Comment: i can’t see any